# Create User and associate acls of resource from java application using admin client

Tags: apache-kafka, strimzi

I am using kafka deployed using strimz operator, I have a use case where I want to create Kafka user from java application in run time and associate ACLs for particular resources, is it doable and how can i achieve that?

Create User and associate ACLs of resource from java application using admin client

I want to know if creating kafka user in run time is possible? and want to know how to acheive it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you configured the Kafka cluster you deployed with Strimzi - i.e. how your `Kafka` custom resource looks like. There are two general ways Strimzi offers for managing users:

- Using the User Operator and the `KafkaUser` custom resources. In this case, the Kubernetes resources are the single source of truth and you cannot use the Kafka Admin API to manage users or ACLs because the User Operator would revert any changes you do. However, you can use the Strimzi `api` library to create the custom resources programmatically from a Java application (you can check out the [examples](https://github.com/scholzj/strimzi-api-examples)).
- Or if you decide to not use the User Operator (=> by not specifying the `.spec.entityOperator.userOperator` field in the `Kafka` custom resource), you can manage users and ACLs with Kafka Admin API and the Kafka CLI tools as with any other Apache Kafka cluster.